# how to make a program run in the background on windows 10

Tags: python

how to make a program written in Python work on a computer without turning on the program?

I tried to do, through the task scheduler in windows, so that when the computer starts, the program opens, but it does not work.

Comment: Why "it does not work"? Could you please add any more info?

Comment: when you start the computer, the program does not turn on